# Aws Athena: How to get RequestID from failed Start-Query-Execution

Tags: amazon-athena

I am getting empty response from failed start-query-execution.
I need to get the requestId of the failed query from start-query-execution.

Comment: which language SDK you are using?

Comment: I am using ruby, thanks

Answer (score 0):

By "failed query" I assume you mean a query that was started but ended up in a failed state. The way you discover that a query ends up in a failed state is to call `Client#get_query_execution`, which takes the query execution ID.

The query execution ID is the only property of the response object from the start query execution call:

```
response = athena.start_query_execution(…)
puts response.query_execution_id
```

If the call throws an error that means that the query never started.

Comment: If there is an error from start_query_execution(because of query ), response.query_execution_id is empty. ** I edited my question with failed start_query_execution **.
ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-ug.pdf
Thanks Theo